# How do I pass a nullptr as an parameter?

Tags: c++, nullptr

```
void Foo::Bar(Baz& x)
{
z = &x;
}

Foo* foo;

foo -> Bar(nullptr);
```

I'm trying to create a generic template, Baz, using just typedef. 
Since z is private and belongs to Foo, I have trouble assigning nullptr to z.

If possible, I'd like the best way to set z to a nullptr without changing too much of the implementation-- unless this is that bad of an implementation.

I was thinking maybe

> (Baz *) 0, or *(void * )0 or the Nullable Class
>   .

Comment: You can pass `nullptr` if the accepted argument is a pointer; in your case, `x` is a reference, therefore it cannot be null.

Comment: Would I be able to keep x as a reference parameter, and still try to achieve what I'm trying to do? When I try passing in just NULL, it's just an integer (0).. Could I cast Bar( (Baz) NULL) instead?

Comment: A reference parameter means it can't be null, so what you're trying to do doesn't make much sense. There are ways around it as seen in the answers, but unless you have a _really_ good, corner-case reason, I don't see why you'd want to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do want to keep this method:

```
void Foo::Bar(Baz& x)
{
  z = &x;
}
```

But still want to be able to set `z` as `nullptr`, you can add an overload for `Bar` that specifically takes a `nullptr` argument:

```
void Foo::Bar(std::nullptr_t nullp)
{
  z = nullp;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want `Foo::Bar` to take nullptr, you need to change parameter to pointer type:

```
void Foo::Bar(Baz* x)
{
   z = x;
}

Foo* foo = new Foo(); 

foo -> Bar(nullptr);
```

Note: you need to allocate object for `foo pointer` before using it, otherwise behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`nullptr` is a pointer, not a valid reference:

```
int &v = nullptr;
```

The gcc complains:

```
bla.cpp:1:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::nullptr_t’
 int &v = nullptr;
```

So you can't pass it as a reference argument. If you want to be able to pass it change `x` to be a (possibly const) pointer:

```
void Foo::Bar(Baz* const x) {
   z = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Foo::Bar(Baz* x)
{
z = x;
}

Foo* foo;
Baz* ptr = NULL;
foo -> Bar(ptr);
```